# How do I check that a string has 2 dashes in it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am attempting to check that a string (`textBox1.Text`) has 2 dashes in it (e.g. XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX). I've had trouble figuring out the best way to do this without learning a whole new thing like Regex.

Right now I have:

```
else if (!textBox1.Text.Contains("-"))
{
    label3.Text = "Incorrect";
}
```

However, this only checks for 1 dash.

Basically, how would I have an if statement check if string `textBox1.Text` has exactly 2 dashes in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the count of dashes in a string with:

```
if str.Count(x => x == '-') != 2 { ... }
```

This basically means "count the number of items (characters) in the string when said item is equal to a dash". Checking it against two will allow you to detect the validity or otherwise of your input string.

---

If you *were* up to learning regular expressions, this is as good a place as any to start. You could check for a specific pattern with something like:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX";
            Regex re = new Regex(@"^[^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*$");
            Console.Out.WriteLine(re.Match(str).Success);
        }
    }
}
```

Now that regex may *look* complicated but it's relatively simple:

```
^       Start anchor.
[^-]*   Zero or more of any non-dash characters.
-       Dash character.
[^-]*   Zero or more of any non-dash characters.
-       Dash character.
[^-]*   Zero or more of any non-dash characters.
$       End anchor.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.count(v=vs.90).aspx) method

```
string input = "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX";

var dashCounter = input.Count(x => x == '-');
```

then

```
if(dashCounter == 2) { }
```

Comment: `string code = textBox1.Text;var dashCounter = code.TakeWhile(x => x == '-').Count();` then `else if (dashCounter == 2) {...}` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: count method is enough!!

Answer (score 2):

Regex isn't really all that complicated, it's worth learning.

Here's a simple solution using LINQ.

```
int dashCount = textbox1.Text.Count(t=>t =='-');
```

Using TakeWhile as another suggested here will only show you the **leading dashes**. For example, to get `2`, you would need a string like `--XX-XX` (note that non-leading dashes wont be counted either).